# How to pretty print conn content?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I tried the following

```
def index(conn, _params) do
    Logger.debug conn
     ......
```

But I get

```
protocol String.Chars not implemented for %Plug.Conn
```

I even tried Apex but that didn't worked either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use [Kernel.inspect/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2) to pretty print `conn`:

```
Logger.debug inspect(conn)
```

Comment: It will print the connection, but unfortunately the result is not pretty at all...

Comment: This answer is not complete. See below.

Answer (score 39):

Use `inspect conn, pretty: true`

... or:

`inspect conn, pretty: true, limit: 30000`

... since `Conn` structures are pretty big.

Comment: You can use `limit: :infinity` as well if you don't mind scrolling a lot.

Comment: this should probably be the accepted answer, though the answer by @rob-raisch is also better than the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

You can indeed use `Kernel.inspect/2` to pretty-print the contents of the `%Plug.Conn{}` using:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  :logger.info inspect(conn, pretty: true)
  ....
end
```

Note that previous answers using `Logger` should mention that you need to `require Logger` before you use it, as in:

```
require Logger

def index(conn, _params) do
  Logger.info inspect(conn, pretty: true)
  ....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`IO.inspect` is well. I used in my side project, like ruby awsome_print