# Log doesn't print when running "mix test"

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to debug while a test is not running, I have my test and I'm trying to print something so I can see the values of a tuple when `mix test` is run. I've tried doing this:

```
require Logger

test "creates element", %{conn: conn} do
    Logger.debug "debugging #{inspect conn}"
    conn = post conn, v1_content_path(conn, :create), content: @valid_attrs
    ...
    ...
end
```

But nothing is printed! It's driving me nuts!
Here is where I read to do what I'm doing [How to pretty print conn content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954457/how-to-pretty-print-conn-content)

**Edit** Also tried with:

```
IO.puts "debugging #{inspect conn}"
```

**Edit** Here the contents of my test_helper.exs

```
ExUnit.start

Mix.Task.run "ecto.create", ~w(-r TestApp.Repo --quiet)
Mix.Task.run "ecto.migrate", ~w(-r TestApp.Repo --quiet)
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.begin_test_transaction(TestApp.Repo)
```

**Edit** Here my whole testing file:

```
defmodule TestApp.ContentControllerTest do
  require Logger
  use TestApp.ConnCase

  @valid_attrs %{title: "Content Title", url: "http://www.content.com"}
  @invalid_attrs %{}

  setup %{conn: conn} do
    conn
      |> put_req_header("accept", "application/json")

    {:ok, conn: conn}
  end

  test "my first test", %{conn: conn} do
    Logger.debug "debugging #{inspect conn}"
  end
end
```

**Edit** Here is the detail of `mix test`:

```
$ mix test
.

Finished in 2.5 seconds (0.6s on load, 1.9s on tests)
1 tests, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 685273
```

Comment: I'm not sure the Logger application is running while you are executing tests.  Rather than using logger, have you tried simply doing IO.puts "debugging #{inspect conn}"

Comment: Are you sure your logger level is not higher than `:debug`? You can read about the level [in the `Logger` docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/logger/Logger.html).

Comment: Where are you expecting the output to show up? It should show up on the console but where is the console when you're dealing with Phoenix?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I'm expecting the output in the console that shows the test results after executing `mix test`

Comment: Do you have `import ExUnit.CaptureLog` in your `test_helper.exs` ? that would capture the logs instead of writing them to the console. I just tried Logger and IO locally and saw both in my console.

Comment: @TattdCodeMonkey thanks for the idea but nothing... edited and added more details...

Comment: I just had this problem, and @TattdCodeMonkey was almost there: The Elixir tutorial puts a `@moduletag :capture_log` tag in the `kv_server_test.exs` file. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### compile_time_purge_level

As pointed out in some comments to your question, the `compile_time_purge_level` can be reduced to the `:debug` level for the test environment by changing the `:logger` config in `config/test.exs`.

### test.exs

```
config :logger,
  backends: [:console],
  compile_time_purge_level: :debug
```

### run tests again

```
mix test
```

Comment: Do you have to point something to look at `test.exs` or does it automatically know to look for this file when running `mix test`? (I still can't get my logger to show up)

Comment: it anticipates the `test.exs` file when the `config.exs` file has the line `import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"` and one runs `mix test` or `MIX_ENV=test mix test`.

Comment: > warning: `:compile_time_purge_level` option for the `:logger` application is deprecated, use `:compile_time_purge_matching` instead.
for Elixir 1.9.